# Custom LinearRegionItem with Arrows in pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyside2, pyqtgraph

I am making an app for data visualization in `Pyqtgraph` and would like to include the feature to be able to select a region and further process it. I can do this by using [LinearRegionItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/linearregionitem.html). But what I also want to show is an arrow with a label to indicate the length of the selection. Below is my attempt using [ArrowItem](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphicsItems/arrowitem.html). The problem with this is that the arrow length is not as expected.

I am assuming the arrow length is wrong because of scaling from scene to view or the other way round. My attempts at understanding the mapping isn't making sense as the output of `mapToScene` doesn't change even if I change its parameter `QPoint`.

I seek your help to guide me in the correct direction.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg

class LinearRegionItemWithArrow(pg.LinearRegionItem):

    def __init__(self, vb, *args, **kwds):
        pg.LinearRegionItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.vb = vb
        self.headLen = 20

        pos1, pos2 = self.getRegion()
        # pos1_vb = self.vb.mapToScene(QtCore.QPoint(pos2, 0)).x()
        # pos2_vb = self.vb.mapToScene(QtCore.QPoint(pos1, 0)).x()
        # print((pos1, pos2), (pos1_vb, pos2_vb))

        tailLen = pos2 - pos1 - self.headLen
        # tailLen_vb = pos2_vb - pos1_vb
        # print(tailLen/tailLen_vb)
        self.arrow1 = pg.ArrowItem(self, 
                                    angle=0, 
                                    headLen=self.headLen,
                                    tipAngle=45,
                                    pos= (pos1, 1), 
                                    tailLen = tailLen, #tailLen_vb if tailLen>2*self.headLen else None,
                                    tailWidth = 3, 
                                    pen=None, 
                                    brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 165, 0), 
                                    pxMode=True)
        
        self.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.updateArrows)

    def updateArrows(self):
        print(self.vb.mapFromScene(QtCore.QPoint(36, 0)))
        pos1, pos2 = self.getRegion()
        # pos1_vb = self.vb.mapToScene(QtCore.QPoint(pos2, 0)).x()
        # pos2_vb = self.vb.mapToScene(QtCore.QPoint(pos1, 0)).x()
        # print((pos1, pos2), (pos1_vb, pos2_vb))

        tailLen = pos2 - pos1 - self.headLen
        # tailLen_vb = pos2_vb - pos1_vb
        # print(tailLen/tailLen_vb)

        self.arrow1.setPos(pos1, 1)
        self.arrow1.setStyle(tailLen = tailLen)# if tailLen>2*self.headLen else None)

data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
win = pg.plot()
plot = win.plot(data, name='data', pen='r', title="Simplest possible plotting example")

lri = LinearRegionItemWithArrow(win.getViewBox(), values=[200, 500])
lri.setZValue(10)
win.addItem(lri)
print(win.mapFromScene(36 , 0))
lri.sigRegionChanged.connect(lambda: win.getViewBox().mapFromScene(QtCore.QPoint(36, 0))) #.mapSceneToView((1.0, 1.0))


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment I shoudl have used `mapSceneToView`  instead of `mapFromScene`. `mapSceneToView` allows to bring points from the plot cordinate system to the window(ViewBox) coordinate system which is what I was looking for. Below is the cleaned up code. Hope this helps others.

```
from PySide2 import QtCore

import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg


class LinearRegionItemWithArrow(pg.LinearRegionItem):

    def __init__(self, plotWindow, *args, **kwds):
        pg.LinearRegionItem.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.plotWindow = plotWindow
        self.headLen = 20

        self.arrow1 = pg.ArrowItem(self, 
                                    angle=0, 
                                    headLen=self.headLen,
                                    tipAngle=45,
                                    pos= (0, 0), 
                                    tailLen = 20, #tailLen_vb if tailLen>2*self.headLen else None,
                                    tailWidth = 3, 
                                    pen=None, 
                                    brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 165, 0), 
                                    pxMode=True)
        self.arrow2 = pg.ArrowItem(self, 
                                    angle=180, 
                                    headLen=self.headLen,
                                    tipAngle=45,
                                    pos= (0, 0), 
                                    tailLen = 20, #tailLen_vb if tailLen>2*self.headLen else None,
                                    tailWidth = 3, 
                                    pen=None, 
                                    brush=pg.mkBrush(255, 165, 0), 
                                    pxMode=True)
        self.updateArrows()
        self.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.updateArrows)
        self.plotWindow.sigRangeChanged.connect(self.updateArrows)  


        self.labels = [pg.TextItem(text='', anchor=(1, 0.5)), pg.TextItem(text='', anchor=(0.5, 0.5)), pg.TextItem(text='', anchor=(0, 0.5))]
        self.updateLabels()
        [self.plotWindow.addItem(l) for l in self.labels]
        self.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.updateLabels)
        self.plotWindow.sigRangeChanged.connect(self.updateLabels)  

    def updateLabels(self):
        pos1, pos2 = self.getRegion()
        for l, p in zip(self.labels, [pos1, 0.5*(pos1+pos2), pos2]):
            l.setPos(p, self.getYPosition())
            l.setText('%.2f'%p)
        self.labels[1].setText('%.2f'%(pos2 - pos1))

    def updateArrows(self):
        pos1, pos2 = self.getRegion()
        self.arrow1.setPos(pos1, self.getYPosition())
        self.arrow2.setPos(pos2, self.getYPosition())

    def getYPosition(self):
        return self.plotWindow.getViewBox().mapSceneToView(QtCore.QPoint(0, 0.1*self.plotWindow.range.height())).y()

data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
win = pg.plot()
plot = win.plot(data, name='data', pen='r', title="Simplest possible plotting example")

lri = LinearRegionItemWithArrow(win, values=[200, 500])
lri.setZValue(10)
win.addItem(lri)

## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if sys.flags.interactive != 1 or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```